# If I delete my Facebook account, what happens to messages I've sent to my friends?

Tags: facebook

I assume that all my data from Facebook servers will be erased permanently, so there's no way I can regain access to my FB account if I delete it.

But what happens to the private messages I sent to my friends? Will they still be visible?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, all the messages won't be visible to you any more cos you deleted your facebook account. :)

Secondly, you friends (ex-friends, cos you deleted them), will all have copies of your facebook chats in their history/cache depending on what software/browser they used.

Thirdly, if you really need to get hold of a copy of the past chats yourself, just remember that facebook sells everything you ever did online, and all the info it can get about you too, so you could probably just email any company that's got a facebook advert or page. :D